# How to create a service to use Twitter API in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, twitter

I would like to implement a service called "Twitter" in order to use Twitter API in my Symfony 2.3 website, so that in Controllers I could use this service like so, for example :

```
$tweet = 'new post on my blog' .$article['title'];
$this->get('twitter')->post('statuses/update', array('status'=> $tweet));
```

But I'm new to API in general, and don't have any ideas on how to properly implement this service and would like to receive some guidance.

Comment: Symfony have a very good doc about creating services: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container. Best bundle for auth via OAuth is https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful this:

```
twitter:
    class: path/to/twitterClass
    file: %kernel.root_dir%/../../vendor/twitter/twitter.php
    arguments:
        token: %parameters.twitterReadToken%
```

You can access it through container:

```
$this->container->get('twitter')->post();
```